# how to copy a table from one hbase cluster to another cluster?

Tags: hbase

I am trying to copy a hbase table from one cluster to another using the copyTable MR in hbase. For running that class im giving the option --peer.adr= and --new.name= and the old table name.

But what happens is the MR checks for a table with 'old table name' given inside the given 'target zookeper cluster' and if present copies it inside the same cluster with the new table name. It is not taking from the cluster from where the MR is run. Am i missing something? Please respond if anyone used this.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's an issue when configuring zookeeper with the zoo.cfg file instead of directly inside hbase-site.xml, see [HBASE-4614](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4614).

Workaround is to remove zoo.cfg from HBase's classpath and add the relevant configurations to hbase-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create Table in Target cluster and than apply this Command.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --peer.adr=Ip:/hbase
```

--new.name=NewTable SourceTable

Or another Way is Export Import. Refer this Link http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html#export